# Re-hosting Flash SWF in Windows Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: flash, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm a flash noob. Okay I'm a video noob. I have a client that handed me some files and the HTML for an object tag. This plays a video with subtitles, and it is hosted on a web server along with the website.

Obviously the SWF file is quite large. So, my question is whether/how I could change this object tag to refer to the SWF file via a URI to Windows Azure Blob storage? I've tried changing the file name to the URI various ways and nothing has worked. Is this even doable?

```
    <object id="csSWF" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="800" height="704" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
        <param name="movie" value="SampleVideo_controller.swf" />
        <param name="scale" value="showall" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#1a1a1a" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="tocdoc=left&amp;showsearch=true&amp;autostart=false&amp;autohide=true&amp;xmp=SampleVideo_config.xml&amp;content=SampleVideo.mp4&amp;thumb=FirstFrame.png&amp;containerwidth=800&amp;containerheight=704&amp;smoothing=true&amp;enablejsapi=true&amp;fullscreen=true&amp;windowbox=false&amp;showbranding=false&amp;showstartscreen=true&amp;showendscreen=true&amp;basecolor=272727&amp;loop=false" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="SampleVideo_controller.swf" width="800" height="704">
            <param name="scale" value="showall" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#1a1a1a" />
            <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="tocdoc=left&amp;showsearch=true&amp;autostart=false&amp;autohide=true&amp;xmp=SampleVideo_config.xml&amp;content=SampleVideo.mp4&amp;thumb=FirstFrame.png&amp;containerwidth=800&amp;containerheight=704&amp;smoothing=true&amp;enablejsapi=true&amp;fullscreen=true&amp;windowbox=false&amp;showbranding=false&amp;showstartscreen=true&amp;showendscreen=true&amp;basecolor=272727&amp;loop=false" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
            <div id="noUpdate">
                <p>The video content presented here requires JavaScript to be enabled in your browser and the latest version of the Adobe Flash Player installed. If you are using a browser with JavaScript disabled please enable it now. Otherwise, please update your version of the free Adobe Flash Player by <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">downloading here</a>. </p>
            </div>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->                    
        </object> 
        <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
```

Comment: I need to restate the question. It is normally straightforward to host a video file or flash video file in Azure Blob storage. I have done this and it works. However, there seems to be something particular to the way this Flash video was generated with an xml config file and subtitles which makes doing so more complicated. I have tried replacing "SampleVideo.mp4" in the above tags with the blob url and that did not work. I also changed it within the config xml file. It might be that this version of Flash can't support a URL or that all the files must be in the same place, or...???

Answer (score 2):

- First you need to create a storage account and upload the SWF to blob
  storage.
- You can do this using Visual Studio and instructions found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683677.aspx#BK_ViewResources)
- From there you will be given a direct URL to the file.
- You should then be able to directly reference it in your code. Note;
  there are two places in your code above that reference the SWF file.

If this still does not work inspect the page and see exactly what the error is. I'm thinking it may be a security feature in Flash preventing you from loading a SWF from an external site.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Hey guys, We've moved a simple Flash page into Azure storage, but it doesn't seem to be loading, properly. not sure how to debug it? Tried using Flash Debugger with Firefox but it says: `no flash files loaded` Can you help please?

Comment: @ApexFred - could you post a new question and include all the relevant details? What do you mean by 'simple flash page'? Is that the html + the swf? , what permissions did you set, what browser, etc. As much detail as possible.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Yes that's HTML + SWF. It got resolved now, it turned out azure blob storage URL locations are case sensitive. my colleague cracked it.